# how to convert string with special characters to int in Java

Tags: java

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(": 2573.01,,");
double d;
```

Above string needs to be converted to double. Problem is with the special characters. How do i remove those ?

Expected Result : d = 2573.01;

Comment: Well what value would you *expect* that to be converted to? It's got a decimal point in it... You need to provide more context about what you're trying to achieve when asking a question.

Comment: as you didn't tell us what value you expect how about trying s.replace("anythinghere", "");

Comment: are all strings you want to convert with this format `:[space][digits].[digits],,`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String st = s.toString();
st = st.replaceAll(":", "").replaceAll(",", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
double d = Double.valueOf(st); //Decimal
int i = (int)d; //No Decimal
```

Comment: nice work, +1 but it doesn't answer OP question. They want to return double not int.

Comment: If you read, it clearly states what gives decimal and what doesn't and this was answered before he said double, when he asked for int.

Answer (score 2):

A nice one liner for you:

```
public double getDoubleFromNoisyString(String s) {
    return Double.valueOf(
               s.replaceAll(
                   "^.*?(-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?).*$",
                   "$1"));
}
```

Basically, it looks for the first value in the string that appears to be in the form of an integer or decimal number (including a leading negative sign) and disregards all other characters.

Answer (score 0):

You could try extracting the number with a regex.

```
String st = s.toString();
st.replaceAll("[^\\d\\.]","");
double n = Double.valueOf(st);
```

Comment: That won't handle a lot of edge cases unfortunately. What if it's a negative number?

Comment: Yes, the regex will need to be amended for any extra requirements, but the question itself only asked for that particular string.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = ":- 2573.01,,";
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\d-.]", "");
double value = Double.parseDouble(str);
System.out.println(value);
```

***Output:***

```
-2573.01
```

Comment: @user3520698 I have checked also for negative numbers.